# Is there a compression method for compressing a group of very similar files, without archiving them?

Tags: file-management, compression, lossless

I want to compress a large nuber of files that have near identical headers, and also some data, however I do not wish to archive them, nor do I wish to zip them individually(because the copression ratio would be much higher if substitutions of similar blocks could be done using a single table).  Does a compression method exist to do this already, or should I implement it myself.

Note: Don't say "Disk space is cheap", because I may want to use this on an embedded system.

Comment: basically you are talking about a compressing filesystem?

Comment: you mean that you want to save space in your files, but don't want to have to compress /extract them everytime you want to use them? Because almost all compressors can concatenate files before compressing... Seems that you want your filesystem to save space, that's it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Don't say "Disk space is cheap", because I may want to use this on an embedded system.

Use squashfs or cramfs.  A single compressed stream, which appears as many separate files once mounted.